# Калькулятор на 3 числа Java

Tags: java

Как сюда добавить 3 число?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Введите пример: ");
    char x = (char) System.in.read();
    char ope = (char) System.in.read();
    char y = (char) System.in.read();
    int xVal = x - 48;
    int yVal = y - 48;
    System.out.print("= ");
    System.out.print(xVal + yVal);
```

// сейчас выводится пример 5+5=10
// нужно чтобы считывался 2ой оператор и число и выводил результат. Пример 10-2*2=16

Вот что получилось

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Введите пример: ");
    char x = (char) System.in.read();
    char ope = (char) System.in.read();
    char y = (char) System.in.read();
    char ope1 = (char) System.in.read();
    char z = (char) System.in.read();
    int xVal = x - 48;
    int yVal = y - 48;
    int zVal = z - 48;
    System.out.print("= ");
```

Я понимаю что тут все злые и проще нагрубить или отправить дальше самой с этим разбираться. Не тратьте ваше время тогда если вы не знаете или не хотите помочь, я потому и задала тут вопрос потому что спросить мне больше не у кого и не знаю как это продолжить. Про поиск в интернете не надо мне говорить, я не на столько ленивая чтобы им в первую очередь не пользоваться.

Comment: Посмотреть внимательно на код и понять что делает каждая строка. Здесь не решебник домашек для начальной школы.

Comment: 1) У вас считываются не _числа_, а _символы_.  2) Введённые символы никоим образом не проверяются на допустимые значения (цифры и знаки операций). 3) Отсутствует логика обработки операций. 4) Пример: `10-2*2=16` не корректен, так как не учитывается приоритет операций, чему учат в школе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код считает примеры с операциями + и -. Например 132-45+12-23. Если хотите можете расширить его на */, но стоит учесть то уже не будет работать, так как нужен будет приоритет операций, но думаю у вас всё получится, если немножко посидеть и подумать! :)

```
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Введите пример: ");
            String example = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print(calculate(example));
        }
    }

    public static Integer calculate(String example){
        example = example.replace(" ", "");

        if(!example.matches("^(\\d{1,}[-+]){1,}\\d{1,}$")){
            throw new RuntimeException("НЕДОПУСТИМЫЙ ФОРМАТ");
        }

        Integer[] ints = Arrays.stream(example.split("[-+]")).map(Integer::parseInt).toArray(Integer[]::new);

        int result = ints[0];
        int counter = 1;
        for (char ch : example.replaceAll("[0-9]","").toCharArray()) {
            if (ch == '-') result -= ints[counter];
            if (ch == '+') result += ints[counter];
            counter++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно преобразовать пришедшую строку из консоли в число.
Пример :

```
Integer.parsInt("4");
```

Или

```
Integer.valueOf("4");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш комментарий мне тоже помог